# Extract the constant part of a SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

Suppose I have a SymPy expression like

```
expr = sqrt(2)*x*y/sin(2)/L
```

How can I extract just

```
sqrt(2)/sin(2)
```

if I don’t know in advance what free symbols are present in the expression? In other words, I would like SymPy to return the part of a monomial that contains no free symbols.

Comment: You can extract the constants with something like `constants = [x for x in expr.as_ordered_factors() if x.is_constant() is True]` and do a reduction (if you are okay with `functools`: `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, constants)`)

Comment: @barrymoo: Please do not post answers as comments.

Comment: Also, I see no good reason for using `if x.is_constant() is True` instead of just `if x.is_constant()` (I see several reasons against it though).

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = sqrt(2)*x*y/sin(2)/L
const = expr.func(*[term for term in expr.args if not term.free_symbols])
```

makes `const` equal to `sqrt(2)/sin(2)`. Although you asked about a product, this approach also works for sums (expr.func will be Mul for products and Add for sums).

In a comment, `barrymoo` pointed out the `is_constant` method. There is a difference between `not term.free_symbols` and `term.is_constant()`. The former only checks the presence of free symbols, which is fast; the latter goes much further, trying numeric evaluation, simplification, and symbolic differentiation in an attempt to prove or disprove that the expression is constant ([reference](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.is_constant)). For example, `sin(x)**2 + cos(x)**2` would be recognized as constant although it has a free symbol.